# InOut.readInt() only working in Windows Java Editor

Tags: java, input, io, inout

At school, I write Java programs with Windows’ Java Editor (console mode). There, `InOut.readInt()` (used for user input) works without problems and I don’t have to import anything.

Now, I have a Java homework for the holidays, and I try to write Java programs on my Mac. In online console Java editors, the line `InOut.readInt()` causes this error:

```
/IntBetween10And100.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        int input = InOut.readInt("Integer --> ");
                    ^
  symbol:   variable InOut
  location: class IntBetween10And100
1 error
```

I already tried import lines (placed before the class) like:

- `import java.*`
- `import java.util.*`
- `import java.util.InOut`
- `import java.io.BufferedStreamReader`

```
import java.util.*;

public class IntBetween10And100 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int input = InOut.readInt("Integer --> ");
    }
}
```

---

```
int input = InOut.readInt("Integer --> ");
```

should produce the line

```
Integer -->
```

but instead, the error message (seen above) appears.

Comment: From my days back at school a remember the teacher provided us with such a class (it is not a class from the java language). Which online java editor? Most probably this indicates that the Windows’ Java Editor includes such a class while the online does not.

Comment: There is no such class as `java.util.InOut`.

Comment: Maybe InOut is a variable of class java.util.Scanner?

Comment: @mayamar, not, it is not: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you are using the "Java-Editor" tool on Windows for writing your Java code.

It turns out that Java-Editor includes a class called `InOut` as an example class.  (You can see it here: http://javaeditor.org/doku.php?id=en:examples).

For various reasons, it is not suitable for use in production code of any kind:

- It is not part of the Java SE class library, or any 3rd-party libraries.
- It is a class in the *default* package
- It has limited functionality, even compared to the real `System.in` and `System.out`
- It would interfere with any application or 3rd party library code that uses `System.in` in the normal way.  (It creates its own `BufferedReader` to wrap `System.in`.  That is liable to capture "type-ahead" input.)

You don't *really* need to use it for educational purposes either.  It is only a wrapper class ...

However, if you want to use `InOut` outside of the Java-Editor context, you could simply download the source code from the page above and add it to your project.  I can't tell you exactly how, but adding classes should be explained in the documentation of the tool you are using now!  (If you are serious about learning Java, I would actually recommend that you download and install a real Java JDK and a real Java IDE on your own computer.)

<sup>The authors have neglected to include an explicit copyright notice in the `InOut.java` file.  However, the Java-Editor site as a whole is licensed as "CC Attribution-Share Alike 4.0 International".</sup>